# Change color of cursor in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How can I change the color of the cursor in my `UITextField`?

Comment: You need to clarify if you're working with Cocoa or Cocoa touch. You could have made this clear by putting actual class names in your question.

Answer (score 99):

With iOS 7 you can simply change `tintColor` property of the `UITextField`. This will affect both the color of the text cursor and the text selection highlight color.

You can do this in code ...

```
textField.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

...

In Swift 4:

```
textField.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

...or in Interface Builder:

[image: screenshot showing how to modify tint of a text field in interface builder]

You can also do this for all text fields in your app using the `UITextField` appearance proxy:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

In Swift 4:

```
UITextField.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Below are simulator screenshots showing what an otherwise ordinary iOS 7 text field looks like with its tint set to red.

**Text cursor screenshot:**

[image: Text cursor screenshot]

**Text selection screenshot:**

[image: Text selection screenshot]

Comment: Strangely for me it DOES NOT WORK if you set it in interface builder: I suspect the item shown is for the UIView itself, "not" the text field aspects per se.

Comment: Same as @Joe Blow, it's working only if you set it programatically. Moreover, it wasn't working on the simulator too, only on a real device. Strange

Comment: It is unbelievable to me that this nonsense is being promoted as an actual solution. This just changes the tintcolor of the text field, which if not white, will modify a lot more than just the cursor. Please DO NOT USE THIS.

Answer (score 14):

In iOS, `UITextfield` has a `textInputTraits` property.  One of the private properties of `UITextInputTraits` is `insertionPointColor`.

Because it's an undocumented property, setting a custom color will probably get your app rejected from the App Store.  If that's not a concern, this should work:

```
[[addNewCategoryTextField textInputTraits] setValue:[UIColor redColor]
                                             forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];
```

Comment: If it is undocumented (private), then you are almost certain to be rejected by Apple.

Comment: This works great in iOS 6. In iOS 7 use the tint color. I will let you know if the app gets rejected, but others have used this trick with no  issue.

Comment: My app was not rejected for using this. However in iOS 10 this solution causes a crash because the `insertionPointColor` trait was removed. **Do not use this solution anymore!**

Answer (score 6):

```
[[self.searchTextField valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"] setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing on Mac OS X, then you can try the `setInsertionPointColor:` method. See [NSTextView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference for more details.

Comment: Yes I tried it by using as:
[addNewCategoryTextField setInsertionPointColor:[UIColor redColor]];

But Im getting the warning as:UITextField may not responds to -setInsertionPointColor

Comment: And when I used the function as:
[addNewCategoryTextField setInsertionPointColor:[NSColor redColor]];
An error is genereted as NSColor not declared use in function.

Comment: That was part of my answer: this message only applies to Mac OS X, not the iPhone.
In your question, you have not specified the platform you are developing on. So I have assumed that it was Mac OS X...

Comment: Not if you're using `UITextField` objects you're not. That's iPhone SDK only.

Answer (score 2):

Durgesh's approach does work.

I also used such KVC solutions many times.
Despite it seems to be undocumented, but it works. Frankly, you don't use any
private methods here - only Key-Value Coding which is legal.

It is drastically different from [addNewCategoryTextField textInputTraits].

P.S. Yesterday my new app appeared at AppStore without any problems with this approach. And it is not the first case when I use KVC in changing some read-only properties (like navigatonBar) or private ivars.

Comment: @Sathish In fact, it's an answer! would it be worth if he has posted a comment?

Answer (score 0):

To change the `cursor` `color` throughout the app for `UITextField/UITextView`, appearance proxy can also be used as below,

```
UITextField.appearance().tintColor = .green
UITextView.appearance().tintColor  = .green
```