# Custom Blinking Insertion Point

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uikit

Is is possible to change the color or any custom features of the blinking insertion point without overwriting private methods (so that there's no issue with deploying to the app store) ?

To be clear, currently it's blinking blue, and I'd like to change it to white for my context, or even black, but not blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about UITextField or UITextView, change the object's tintColor property to the color you would like your cursor to be.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this has been answered, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606007/change-uitextfield-and-uitextview-cursor-caret-color/18945907#18945907