# UITextView Cursor Color not changing iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to set the cursor color of a UITextView based on a user's preferences. They select what color they want with a button.

By default, the textview's cursor color is white. When the user presses the button, it might change to green:

```
[_textView setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[_textView setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

I am sure that this method call is working because the textview's text changes color, just not the cursor...

Comment: My experience shows that calling `setTintColor:` changes the color of the text view's caret.

Comment: @rmaddy I think this might be a bug in iOS 7.1 regarding global tints such as [UIView appearance] because there's nothing I'm doing that's out of the ordinary. This should work...

Comment: From my experience (in iOS7.1 as well), indeed tintColor sets the cursor color.

Comment: I just checked it: if I am not just in change mode, press the button, they text and the caret will change color. If I have the text in change mode, the caret's color will stay blue.

Comment: @vikingosegundo not sure what you mean by change mode

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to recreate your behavior: If I change the tint and text color while the text view isn't selected (aka: not first responder), everything will work as expected.

But if I first select it, by tapping it and than change the color by button press, they caret's (tint) color won't change.

Here is a workaround:

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender 
{
    [_textView setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [_textView setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    if([_textView isFirstResponder]){
        [_textView resignFirstResponder];
        [_textView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have views that are affected by keyboard appearance transitions and the resign/become calls above would cause some undesirable behavior. I was able to eliminate this by wrapping the calls like so:
`[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

[_textView resignFirstResponder];

[_textView becomeFirstResponder];

[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];`

Comment: You don't need to make this trick with changing responder status you just need to call `textView.tintColorDidChange()`. See details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53332199/2742194

Answer (score 6):

I'm using small hack in UITextViewDelegate method:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let color = textView.tintColor
    textView.tintColor = .clear
    textView.tintColor = color
}
```

**UPD**

more technological way:

1) implement method in extension:

```
extension UITextView {
    func resetTintColor(){
        let color = tintColor
        tintColor = .clear
        tintColor = color
    }
}
```

2) in an UITextViewDelegate implementation:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.resetTintColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[_textView reloadInputViews];
```

And in Swift

```
textView. reloadInputViews()
```

Then you won't need to handle keyboard incoming and going.

Comment: It had worked for me very fine, `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder` was making keyboard view go and come back. May I know how are you implementing the solution and for what?

Comment: Basically, I set the text view's tintColor, then resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder, then I call reloadInputViews after that. The animation is not happening, but the cursor is not changing its tint color.

Comment: I guess you have implemented it rightly, I will check the solution again for you and get back to you. But it had worked for me for the same scenario.