# How to set the text field letter slightly right side

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have two text fields, for **username** and **password**. I created designs for both `uitextfield` using the layer property.

When enter some text, values are displayed starting from the edge like below:

[image: bad layout]

Is there any possible to move that username slightly to the right as a starting point for `uitextfield`?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView *paddingView_textFieldFullName = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 35)];
yourTextFieldName.leftView = paddingView_textFieldFullName;
yourTextFieldName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
yourTextFieldName.text = @"";
yourTextFieldName.delegate=self;
```

try this code, 
I hope helps to you.

Comment: yes its worked. IS that possible to change the cursor color from blue to white.

Comment: Yes, you can change color of cursor. Set tint color of UITextField. Check this:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/18945907/4708139

Answer (score 1):

[UITextField Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/leftView), this class has a overlay views inside it like **leftView** and **rightView** so just create a blank view and add it to your textField's leftView.

Also you can check these. [UITextfield leftView/rightView padding on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371018/uitextfield-leftview-rightview-padding-on-ios7)

[Text inset for UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694411/text-inset-for-uitextfield)