# objective c delegate method for texttview delegate method

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

[image: text menu]

Above is my image in that there was menu for cut,copy etc. So I added following code:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
     [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
         [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
         [self resignFirstResponder];

    }];
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

So I removed that pop up by adding above code  but the blue color effect is still there when I double click on that link which is I embeded in textview

How to remove this blue color selection on textview? It appears when I double click on it. I do not want to appear that.

Comment: You want to disable selection or only the visual effect? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606007/change-uitextfield-and-uitextview-cursor-caret-color ?

Comment: i want to disable that blue effect means visualisation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

You could disable selection for the textview, you would need to subclass UITextView and override the method below, see this previous question, [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview).

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```