# It's Possible to change default selection color in UITextField iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, selection-color

Default selection color is blue as  - I required to change it clear color?

I know If I change tint color then that color will be set when I select ant text but my question **When I set clear color as tint color then there should be no color displaying for selection of text but It is taking gray color as default.**

if It is posiible then How? and please provide source code.

**This is what happens when tint color is blue**
[image]

if i set tintColor = clear color than display gray color.

**This happens when tint color is set as clear color, its taking gray color as default that I dont want**

```
textField.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

[image]
Please help me.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think it should be tint color. try it,.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of cursor in text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190352/change-color-of-cursor-in-text-field)

Comment: @Larme he dont want any color on selection, that's the question

Comment: @Larme Now read the question

Comment: Is this any specific requirement from client? As I am not getting the purpose of making the tint color clear... The resulting UI would be rather confusing.

Comment: Yes, it's specific client requirement @sweta.me if possible than provide solution.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Tried several combination. None worked. Even if you make the background same as the tint color, gradient difference would be there,

Comment: background is different

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible because if you change the cursor color to clear it will not show you the selected text so you have to pick some color for this. You can use a color wchich is very close to transparent by giving its RGB value.

Use below line of code

```
 textfield.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

It will look like this

[image]

Comment: how can i set cursor color?

Comment: Cursor color is automaticallty set when you change the tint color

Comment: it's not my answer please read my question carefully! and Thanks

Comment: I have one question if your selection color is clear then how you are going to show the selected text ? @ChandreshKachariya

Comment: Your question is right, But i required to set clear color and it's values display in other places.

Comment: Also let me know if you are able to find the solution @ChandreshKachariya

Comment: if possible then started this question with upvote and check daily @Ali Farhan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136141/discussion-between-chandresh-kachariya-and-ali-farhan).

Answer (score -1):

Change tint color of the text field.[image]

Comment: There is an option to selecte ur required color.