# When text is selected everything becomes white ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been working with JLStickerTextView. it has a JLAttributedTextView which basically extends UITextView.

My problem is When I select a text inside the JLAttributedTextView, everything becomes white.

Normally it looks like this

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17532073/38668425-bc8af2ce-3e65-11e8-8998-89ece0e48ae1.png

But after selecting the texts, it becomes like this

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17532073/38668470-d4101e56-3e65-11e8-9dd7-6da03037b32f.png

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341269/its-possible-to-change-default-selection-color-in-uitextfield-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to clear the tint color from the textview. And it solved the issue. Thanks.