# Catalyst textview caret color

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

How I can change caret color in textView for Catalyst version of my app? I tried to use

```
textView.tintColor
```

but it doesn't works on Catalyst.

I mean

[image]

Comment: There is a working answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537039/change-prompt-color-for-uitextfield-or-uitextview-on-mac-catalyst

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[[textView textInputTraits] setValue:[UIColor redColor]
                                             forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];

Sourced from here, but it may be private:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4273440/1043615

One comment says it no longer works from iOS 10 but it works OK for Catalyst.