# Change prompt color for UITextField or UITextView on Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, mac-catalyst

How can I programmatically change the color of the prompt on mac catalyst for an UITextField?

The prompt exist but with the same color as UITextField.

The prompt is showing the right color on iOS.

I unsuccessfully tried ***.tintColor***

[Code + iOS and Mac Catalyst result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z69w4.jpg)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, I think I've found a workaround for this. You can use the key-value coding paradigms to get at the insertionPointColor property (which is what you ultimately need to set). Here is an example of setting the caret color to red. Be careful to only do this when targeting Mac Catalyst, as using tintColor on iOS is proper.

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
let textInputTraits = myTextView.value(forKey: "textInputTraits") as? NSObject
textInputTraits?.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "insertionPointColor")
#endif
```

---

As of 2022 this works perfectly for both `UITextField` and `UITextView` on Mac Catalyst builds running on a Mac.

Comment: Thx so much!!! How on earth did you find this out? :D ... and why can't it just respond to tintColor...

Comment: @MatthiasFranz he just have Obj-C background 

Comment: Works as expected.  Hopefully we'll be able to use the regular `textView.tintColor` in an upcoming update